# Write a list in a single line in C#

Tags: c#, list, console.writeline

If I have a list

```
var myList = new List<string>();
```

and I add a couple of strings

```
myList.Add("Hello");
myList.Add("World");
myList.Add("!");
```

How do I print the entire list on one line? If I try `Console.WriteLine(myList);` the console prints *"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"* instead of *"Hello World !"*. I've tried

```
myList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

but that prints *"Hello"*, *"World"* and *"!"* on separate lines instead of on one line. How would I go about printing the list on one line?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList));`

Comment: Search for “convert list to string”.

Comment: Use string.Join like the duplicate and suggested answers. Unlike some answers in the duplicate, there is no need for ToArray.

Comment: Actually, ```myList.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i + " ")); ``` is simpler...

Answer (score 3):

Use `string.Join` like this

```
  var myList = new List<String>{ "Hello", "world", "!" };
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", myList ));
```

The result will be:  `Hello world !`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) all the items of `myList` into *single* `string`, then print it:

```
 // Hello
 // World
 // !
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList));
```

Or (let's change delimiter)

```
 // Hello World !
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", myList));
```